# Cycle method in Visual C# and .NET 4.0

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have created a new Windows Forms Application with C# and .NET 4.0, and I have a function that must be called automatically every 60th of a second.  My problem, is that I do not know where to call this function.  .NET forms don't appear to have a built-in on-update event.

How would I go about getting this function called every 60th of a second?
Sorry if it is a beginner question.

Comment: This appears to allow the time difference to work, however, I still am uncertain where I should be placing it.

Comment: If it has to be ***exactly*** every 60th of a second, 16.7ms, you won't get much luck in Windows. Timer resolution starts getting pretty fuzzy below 40ms or so. The best you can do is attempt to signal every 16ms, calculate how many 60ths of a second should have elapsed at the moment the timer deploys, and fire them off on that timer interval. Don't expect rock solid timing at this resolution.

Comment: Very important point, @spender. +1 on the comment. In fact, I'm going to amend my answer to that effect.

Comment: Not sure why you are looking for an "Update" event. Are you assuming 60Hz refresh?

Comment: Yes, I was attempting to get a 60Hz drawing engine.  Realtime video update like in a game.  XNA is dieing slowly, and I am experimenting with alternatives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set up a Timer to invoke a callback every 16 ms (which is 1/60 sec).

**Important point as mentioned by @spender: If you are requiring *very* precise timing on this, eg *exactly* every 1/60 sec precision, you will not be satisfied with this solution. Windows does not natively do high-resolution timing in that vein very well. Props to @spender for the mention.**

Here's a sample class with a rough outline of how it might look in a plain vanilla class, so you'd need to adapt it to your form:

You might also want to call this on a background thread, but if you're new to WinForms, we'll start in small chunks. Let's try the timer first, then go from there.

```
class Demo{

   System.Timers.Timer myTimer;

   void InitializeTimer(){
      myTimer = new Timer(16); // elaps every 1/60 sec , appx 16 ms.
      myTimer.ElapsedEventHandler+=new ElapsedEventHandler(myTimerEventHandler); //define a handler
      myTimer.Enabled=true; //enable the timer.
   }

   void myTimerEventHandler(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e){
     // do your thing here
   }
}
```

**EDIT: Extra demo code for background thread creation and Invoked-based GUI update**

As noted in my comment below, this is not as polished as I would like it, but I think it illustrates the salient points. It defines a BackgroundWorker thread to move the thread invocations to the background; the thread callback checks for the need to call Invoke, and calls right back to itself across a delegate invocation to allow for the custom form update in the "else" block of the "if (InvokeRequired)" statement. In a nutshell, a background thread starts, and starts a timer; when the timer elapses, it calls the updater on the background thread, which checks to see if Invoke must be called, and if it is, performs the thread context switch back to the GUI thread through the recall to the method, which then performs the GUI update. Put your custom update code in that "else" block. I hope this helps!!!

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    delegate void FormUpdateDelegate(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e);
    public BackgroundWorker backgroundThread; 
    System.Timers.Timer foo;
    Random colorgen = new Random();
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        backgroundThread = new BackgroundWorker();
        backgroundThread.DoWork+=new DoWorkEventHandler(backgroundThread_DoWork);
        backgroundThread.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    public void formUpdater(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            FormUpdateDelegate d = new FormUpdateDelegate(formUpdater);
            Invoke(d, new object[] { sender, e });
        }
        else
        {
            // Do your form update here
            this.label1.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(colorgen.Next());
        }
    }

    public void backgroundThread_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        foo = new System.Timers.Timer(16);
        foo.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(formUpdater);
        foo.Start();
    }

}
```

Comment: So I have made a class such as this, now how to I make the program use it? xD

Comment: Well, that was intended as a very rough demo for you to adapt into your existing form, but we can work it out. In your form's class, add the "guts" of this demo class (the code inside the class declaration). Provide the specifics of what you want to do when the timer elapses in `myTimerEventHandler`. Then, in something like the form's `Load` event, call `InitializeTimer()`;

Comment: Oh!  Thank you! That gives my application a ticking heartbeat, now things can start happening.  Thanks!

Comment: I'm delighted I was able to help!

Comment: 'System.Timers.Timer' does not contain a definition for 'ElaspedEventHandler' and no extension method 'ElaspedEventHandler' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Timers.Timer' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: I kept editing it, my fault.  I think I got the bugs worked out.  I will get back to you in a few seconds here.

Comment: Ah, this cycles, but REALLY slowly, also, it doesn't have a way to pause the cycling during message popups :P  Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Well, the precision of the timing is definitely a concern. The problem is how to put this where it can fire more rapidly, but that entails some work that will be very odd to someone relatively new to .NET programming. What are you needing to do with each timer invocation (every 16.7 ms)?

Comment: Draw game sprites, calculate collision, physics, etc.  If there is a way to do this in C# without .NET I would, but it has the window, and it has the control over PNG's.  I don't know how to do that myself :P

Comment: Well, C# is inexorably linked to .NET, so you can't separate them. Getting the kind of response you're wanting is going to be difficult at best. The next step to getting the updates more responsive is put them on a background thread, but you have to do a context switch back to the GUI thread to make UI updates. Not trivial for a newcomer to C#, unfortunately. Let me see if I can cook something up for you.

Comment: See, my big problem, is my large engine currently sits on XNA.  I want to get it off of XNA however, and try to get some older platforms to be supported.  My hardware from before 2004 doesn't seem to support it.  I want at least another 3 years back.

Comment: Okay, this is not nearly as polished as it should be, but it illustrates at least the basic way to start up a background thread, fire up a timer that expires every 16 milliseconds, and then invokes an update to the GUI thread to (for example purposes) change the color of a text label. It 1) creates a BackgroundWorker thread, 2) defines a Delegate to allow for the calling of the update method across the thread context switch, and 3) Performs an Invoke to update the GUI. I have revised the answer to include the extra information. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I just setup this in a console application, and it runs fine every second:

```
        var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);

        timer.Enabled = true;
        timer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(delegate(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs eventArgs)
                                                         {
                                                             Console.WriteLine("Elapsed");
                                                         });
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is inside a console application, and I need to know where to place such code in a Windows Forms Application.  Because I am not too familiar with the framework, it seems that I cannot find a location for an update event.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bad practice to hope on system timers when you need precision at least `20` times per second.

I would recommend to use cycles like

```
Timespan timePerFrame = Timespan.FromMilliseconds(16);

while (_isRunning)
{
    Stopwatch timer = Stopwatch.StartNew()

    // Action.

    while (timer.ElapsedMilliseconds < timePerFrame) { /* Nothing? */ }
}
```

That will give you the full precision, if your system supports high-precision stopwatch. ([`.IsHighResolution`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.stopwatch.ishighresolution.aspx) field).

Comment: This may well work if you're happy to spin during the wait. Seems pretty costly in terms of CPU to me.

Comment: I just need something for cycling a draw event for drawing changing images on the screen.  60FPS is what I am looking for.

Comment: @user1708977 then just simple System.Timers.Timer.